# Is it possible to remote control iOS camera and music without a helper app?

Tags: ios, bluetooth

I'm making a hardware device that I can program to send any Bluetooth BLE code. How do I make it control my iPhone to:

- take a picture
- play/pause music
- next slide in a PPT presentation

These are things that happen on the phone. Phone takes a picture, phone plays music, etc.

Do I need to install or make a companion app on the phone, or can my hardware device just send the right BLE code(s) to the phone?

Comment: You will need to implement the HID over GATT profile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create an app if you want some custom features. 
If you want to control audio (stop,play etc.) you can simply send commands. 
On the other hand you should create an app, an instance of EAAccessory and start steam from it.

More info

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ExternalAccessoryPT/ExternalAccessoryPT.pdf

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ExternalAccessory/Reference/EASession_class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Thanks, Dmitry, but where can I find the spec for exactly which BLE commands to send for audio/camera/PPT etc?

Comment: You can read "Building iPhone OS Accessories. Use the iPhone Accessories API to Control and Monitor Devices". This book have almost all knowledge about communication with non native devices. Remember you should get an apple chips to manufacture your gadgets, if you want to connect them without bluetooth.

Answer (score 0):

The Bluetooth camera remote for iOS is mapped as a Bluetooth Keyboard where the physical photo/shutter button triggers Volume Up.

It’s identical to how the iPhone physical volume buttons (-/+) can be used to take photos and videos while running the Camera app.

If you press the photo/shutter button on the Bluetooth camera remote, outside of the Camera app, it will raise the volume by 1 bar.

Apple doesn’t let you tamper with the system volume, so if you try to add a listener to an AVAudioSession, to determine if the Volume has changed, your app may be rejected.